Unable to Connect Unity TCP using Fixed IP from GCP (Google Cloud Platform)
I am not fluent in English, so I’m using a translator. Please bear with me if some of the intended meaning doesn’t come across clearly.
I’m currently working on connecting a Unity TCP client and server using an external IP address obtained from Google Cloud Platform (GCP). However, despite numerous attempts, I am unable to make a successful connection with the fixed IP from GCP. I’m listing below the things I have already checked and the issues that persist. If anyone could point out any overlooked aspects or potential solutions, I would really appreciate it.

I am experiencing issues with a TCP connection in Unity using a static IP created on Google Cloud Platform (GCP). I attempted to establish a server-client connection using TCP with an external IP assigned by GCP, but after multiple tries, I am still unable to resolve the failure described below, and thus unable to use the external IP. If anyone has suggestions on what I might have overlooked, or if you have potential solutions or insights on the cause, I would greatly appreciate your help.
Confirmed Functional Components
Internal IP Address Port Forwarding: Verified NAT settings by logging into the router. Ping Test: Confirmed active network connection by pinging the GCP server’s IP from the client.
GCP Firewall Rules: Source IP Range: 0.0.0.0/0 TCP Protocol: Allowed Direction: Ingress Port and Static IP: No issues identified.
VM Instance Settings: Firewall: HTTP and HTTPS traffic allowed.
GCP SSH Remote Server Access: Successfully logged into the server with the static IP created by GCP.
Local Testing with 127.0.0.1: Local testing was successful.
Issues: Unity Error: Result: Unable to connect due to the target computer actively refusing the connection.
Attempts to Disable Windows Firewall: Tried disabling Windows Firewall but encountered the same failure. Client Code Execution Delay: Delayed client code execution by 5 seconds to ensure the server starts first, but no change in outcome.
Unity Source Code Setup: The server and client codes were assigned to separate components on empty GameObjects in Unity.
Server.cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Server : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<ServerClient> clients;
    List<ServerClient> disconnectList;
    TcpListener server;
    bool serverStarted;
    private const int PORT = 8000; // Set port number
    private const string IP_ADDRESS = "0.0.0.0"; // Allow connections from all IPs

    public void ServerCreate()
    {
        clients = new List<ServerClient>();
        disconnectList = new List<ServerClient>();

        try
        {
            server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(IP_ADDRESS), PORT);
            server.Start();
            Debug.Log($"Server started on port {PORT}.");
            StartListening();
            serverStarted = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogException(e);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        ServerCreate();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (!serverStarted) return;

        foreach (ServerClient c in clients)
        {
            if (!IsConnected(c.tcp))
            {
                c.tcp.Close();
                disconnectList.Add(c);
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                NetworkStream s = c.tcp.GetStream();
                if (s.DataAvailable)
                {
                    string data = new StreamReader(s, true).ReadLine();
                    if (data != null)
                        OnIncomingData(c, data);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < disconnectList.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log($"{disconnectList[i].clientName} disconnected.");
            clients.Remove(disconnectList[i]);
            disconnectList.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    bool IsConnected(TcpClient c)
    {
        try
        {
            if (c != null && c.Client != null && c.Client.Connected)
            {
                if (c.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead))
                    return !(c.Client.Receive(new byte[1], SocketFlags.Peek) == 0);
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    void StartListening()
    {
        server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptTcpClient, server);
    }

    void AcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        TcpListener listener = (TcpListener)ar.AsyncState;
        ServerClient newClient = new ServerClient(listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar));
        clients.Add(newClient);
        Debug.Log($"Client connected: {newClient.clientName}");
        StartListening();
    }

    void OnIncomingData(ServerClient c, string data)
    {
        if (data.Contains("&NAME"))
        {
            c.clientName = data.Split('|')[1];
            Debug.Log($"{c.clientName} connected.");
            return;
        }
    }

    public void Broadcast(string data, List<ServerClient> cl)
    {
        foreach (var c in cl)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(c.tcp.GetStream());
                writer.WriteLine(data);
                writer.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.LogException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ServerClient
{
    public TcpClient tcp;
    public string clientName;

    public ServerClient(TcpClient clientSocket)
    {
        clientName = "Guest";
        tcp = clientSocket;
    }
}

Client.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool socketReady;
    TcpClient socket;
    NetworkStream stream;
    StreamWriter writer;
    StreamReader reader;
    private const string SERVER_IP = " "; // GCP Static IP
    private const int SERVER_PORT = 8000; // Client port number

    public void ConnectToServer()
    {
        if (socketReady) return;

        try
        {
            socket = new TcpClient(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
            stream = socket.GetStream();
            writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            socketReady = true;
            Debug.Log("Connected to server.");
            SendClientName("Guest" + UnityEngine.Random.Range(1000, 10000)); // Random client name
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Socket error: {e.Message}");
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(ConnectAfterDelay());
    }

    private IEnumerator ConnectAfterDelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5); // Delay to allow server startup
        ConnectToServer();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (socketReady && stream.DataAvailable)
        {
            string data = reader.ReadLine();
            if (data != null)
                Debug.Log(data); // Display received data
        }
    }

    void SendClientName(string clientName)
    {
        Send($"&NAME|{clientName}");
    }

    void Send(string data)
    {
        if (!socketReady) return;

        writer.WriteLine(data);
        writer.Flush();
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        CloseSocket();
    }

    void CloseSocket()
    {
        if (!socketReady) return;

        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
        socket.Close();
        socketReady = false;
    }
}

